# TransientObjectException when searching 'by entity'

Tags: hibernate, object, jpa, transactional, transient

I have a two-part question about my Spring MVC 3 with JPA/Hibernate setup.

First, it doesn't matter whether I put a @Transactional annotation on my service methods, it just always works and I find that rather strange. I am used to methods complaining they don't have a transaction when I forget to add the @Transactional annotation.

This is my transactions setup in the application-context.xml file.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Secondly, when I use a service method to fetch a Category, I get a Category object. As far as I can tell it's not a proxy, but a real object, with most properties set. When I use that Category to search for Courses it goes wrong:

```
public List<Course> findCourses(Category category) {
    Query queryGood = entityManager.createQuery("select c from Course c join fetch c.company where c.category.id = :categoryId");
    Query queryBad = entityManager.createQuery("from Course c where c.category = :category");

    queryGood.setParameter("categoryId", category.getId());
    queryBad.setParameter("category", category);

    List<Category> categoriesGood = queryGood.getResultList(); // THIS WORKS!
    List<Category> categoriesBad = queryBad.getResultList(); // THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION
    return null;

}
```

This execution of queryBad results in the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved 
transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
nl.myapp.domain.Category; nested exception  is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance
- save the transient instance before flushing: nl.myapp.domain.Category
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:298)
```

Do you know why (1) my application fetches data without using the @Transactional annotation and 2) why Hibernate throws this TransientObjectException?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind about this. Hibernate was reacting just the way it should. I used one @Transactional service method to get the Category and used that Category as input for another @Transactional service method. When you do that, Hibernate creates a new session for the new second service method call (since it has its own Transactional annotation) and can't find the Category in the new session. That is why it throws a TransientObject exception. I am now just using the Category's id as a parameter to the seciond service method call and this works.